# Why is the partial deriviate of a harmonic function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

i want to understand the following question. We need to show: $u$, a harmonic function $u:U \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, U is an open subset.$U \subset \mathbb{C}$ 
Show that the partial derviviate to z is holomorphic.

We know that $u$ is harmonic. This means, that $u$ is two times coninously differentiable und that u suffits the mean-value property. How do I show, that the partial deriviate to $z$ is holomorphic?

Greetings and thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: write the harmonic condition in terms of the partial derivatives with respect to $z, \bar z$ and then the claim follows trivially by cauchy Riemann

Comment: Sorry, I made mistakes when posting this question.